# NSRegularExpression for retrieving numbers from a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, xcode, nsregularexpression

I had used NSScanner for retrieving numbers from below text. But sometimes the result is not like what is expected. Heard that NSRegularExpression class which is available fro iOS 4 is better to do this type of extraction. As I am a beginner on NSRegularExpression, I found the documentation provided by Apple is difficult to understand. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Input:

> 1D03 04 10 17 47 D24--

Output:

> 03 04 10 17 47 24

The first 5 sets of numbers should be less than 59 and last set should be less than 39.

Comment: The difficulty with either `NSScanner` or `NSRegularExpression` is going to be mapping all of the possible input patterns to the desired output pattern.  It is probable that you could deal with all of the substitutions with a single regex pattern, if the three cases are the only input patterns expected.  I could post generic regex code from one of my implementations if helpful; but it resembles that provided in the Apple docs, honestly.

Comment: @iSharreth May be this will help http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/294511-nsregularexpression-only-finds-single-occurrence-of-my-match.html#294512

Answer (score 2):

try this ..

```
NSString *originalString = @"1D03 04 10 17 47 D24---";

NSLog(@"%@", originalString);
NSMutableString *strippedString = [NSMutableString 
                                   stringWithCapacity:originalString.length];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet 
                           characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789  "];

while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    NSString *buffer;
    if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&buffer]) {
        [strippedString appendString:buffer];

    } else {
        [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];
    }
}

NSLog(@"%@", strippedString);
```

Comment: Nice.  Although this fails with the second input line where '2Q' is expected to give '20'. (Unless that was a typographical error in the initial question.)  It also fails in the third line due to lack of spaces. Again, assuming the spacing was an output requirement.

Comment: Now it is.  After my comment was posted, the OP was edited to delete 2 of the three divergent patterns.  Originally the questioner gave three patterns that needed to be satisfied.

Comment: Yes, take a look at the edits that the original poster made.  When I responded to your answer, he had three input patterns and three output patterns listed in the question.  After my comment, he deleted two of the three (the two that your scanner did not satisfy.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4186/discussion-between-alan-duncan-and-userar)

Comment: @userar, Your answer gives `103` for `1D03`, but the OP needs just `03`.

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
NSString *string = @"1D03 04 10 17 47 D24---";

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\S*(\\d{2})\\S*"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];


NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                                                      withTemplate:@"$1"];
```

This Regular Expression matches everything which starts and ends with 0 or more non withspace Charcters (\S) and has in the middle two digits (\d). The matches are replaced by the tow digits in the middle of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Tobias. It is working perfectly. I am using this pattern for the ocr output of powerball,megamillaion,etc..tickets from tesseract engine. How can I edit this Regular expression for getting the output even if the whitespace character is missing? For example, if the input is 1D03 0410 17 47 D24--- the output should be 03 04 10 17 47 24

Comment: Also the first 5 sets of number will only be between 01 and 59, and the last set will only be between 01 and 39.